# PSPDFKit give error `documentRef is nil , cannot get pageRef`

Tags: objective-c, pspdfkit

How would i know `file document` is `corrupt` or cannot be `loaded` in `PSPDFKit`?

How delegate method should i implement in `PSPDFKit` to know document is `corrupt` or cannot be `loaded`?

The problem is file document does exist?? but don't know is file corrupt or not.

If i know then could download new file document if its corrupt.

Thanks you all !!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the main developer of PSPDFKit.

You can use the [document.isValid][1] property to determine if the document source is valid or not.

Comment: Why PDF file gets corrupted thats main question?